# Should Kernel Ridge Regression with linear kernel yield same results as Ridge regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, kernel-trick, ridge-regression

I'm comparing the performance of different regressors from scikit-learn for fitting some data.
I would have expected that Ridge regression and Kernel Ridge regression both yield the same model/performance for the same training set and the parameter alpha, but the performance is different. Why is that?